# How to compute standard deviation leaving out rows identified by levels of two other vectors in R?

Tags: r, loops, match, aggregate, standard-deviation

I compute standard deviation for firms in the same sector and same region with the aggregate argument

`sd_lsales <- aggregate(lsales, by=list(region, sector), function(x) sd (x, na.rm=TRUE))`

for a dataframe like:

```
    region  sector                lsales
1   Vienna  Food                  363000000
2   Vienna  Other Manufacturing     5930000
3   Vienna  Food                  150000000
...
505 Berlin  Food                   39200000
506 Berlin  Manufacturing         203900000
507 Berlin  Manufacturing         298000000
508 Berlin  IT                     30339200  

The whole data.frame consists of
852 Regions
52 Sectors
28052 observations
```

Is there any way to compute standard deviations for all other industries in the same region except for the sector mentioned in the same row?

For example in Row 1 I want to compute the standard deviation of lsales (=”log sales”) for all sectors in Vienna except for sector “Food”.
In Row 506 I want standard deviation of lsales for all sectors in Berlin except for sector “Manufacturing” etc.

As I have to do this for 852 Regions, 52 sectors I try to figure out if it is possible to achieve this with something like a “loop” or “if else” ... argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
df1$sd_lsales <- unsplit(lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$Region), function(x) {
                  sd1 <- sapply(unique(x$Sector), function(y) {
                  i1 <- x$Sector!=y
                  sd(x$lsales[i1])

                    })
                 sd1[x$Sector]
               }

             ), df1$Region)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Region = c("Vienna", "Vienna", "Vienna", "Berlin", 
"Berlin", "Berlin", "Berlin"), Sector = c("Food", "Other Manufacturing", 
 "Food", "Food", "Manufacturing", "Manufacturing", "IT"), lsales = c(363000000L, 
5930000L, 150000000L, 39200000L, 203900000L, 298000000L, 30339200L
 )), .Names = c("Region", "Sector", "lsales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "505", "506", "507", "508"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this once

```
library(dplyr)

sd_lsales <- aggregate(lsales, by=list(region, sector), function(x) sqrt((sum((x-mean(x))^2) - (x-mean(x))^2)/n()-1)   )
```

Comment: Hardik, sorry for my late reply, i used the dplyr package with your code and the answer was: Error in n() : This function should not be called directly . Not sure what causes that ...

Comment: @ Hardik: tried lenght(x) now. Produces NaNs and standard deviations which are different from akrun's. if you copy paste df1 from his solution and compare it with the results of your code. I checked the results of akrun's code again and they are correct.